# Inconsistent results from logical formula in PowerPivot

Tags: excel, powerquery, powerpivot

I need some help troubleshooting a formula in PowerPivot.  I am comparing the invoice total on a summary table to the sum of the line amounts on a detail table.  The formula sometimes returns that the fields don't match when they do in fact match.

Thanks for taking time to read my question!

**Data Model**

An external/OLAP data model consisting of two tables `InvSummary` and `InvDetail`.  These tables are linked by `InvoiceNumber`.

**Calculated fields**

- `Total Revenue` defined on `InvSummary` as `=SUM(InvSummary[Total Invoice Amt])`
- `Total Line Amt` defined on `InvDetail` as
  `=SUM(InvDetail[Line Amt])`
- `InvAmtMatch` defined on `InvSummary` as `=[Total Revenue]=[Total Line Amt]`

**Sample data**

In the images below, the fields have exactly the digits shown, no extra decimal places that are rounded.

*Pivot table*

The first 4 columns are the pivot table.  The fifth column is a manual check on equality of Revenue and Line Amt using relative cell references.

[image]

*Invoice Summary*

[image]

*Invoice Detail*

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fairly sure this is a [precision problem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/floating-point-arithmetic-inaccurate-result) and due to how power query and excel manage floating point numbers.

Observe the following in PQ:

```
let
    Source = 0.1+0.2=0.3
in
    Source
```

Result:

[image]

In Excel:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer and especially for the precision problem link.  It validates that a viable workaround for this "feature" is ROUND().  I changed the measure to be =ROUND([Total Revenue],2)=ROUND([Total Line Amt],2) and it works correctly.